# Why does the 'p:nth-child(1)' not work in my html?

Tags: html, css

When I used `p:nth-child(1){color: white;}` in my style tag it didn't work.

```html
body {
  background-color: #162b85;
}

button,
p:nth-child(1) {
  color: white;
}

<br />
<p class="center">Register your account
</p>
<div class="container">
    <button type="submit" class="color">Sign up</button>
  <p class="center">Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign
    in</a>.</p>
</div>
```

I was expecting the result of the first p tag in the HTML code above to be white but it was black. I was wondering could the br tag have caused it. When I removed the br tag in the body tag, the color of the p tag changed to white.

Comment: Welcome to the site; please edit your question to include a [mcve] -- that means enough HTML and CSS in the question itself (as text, not images) so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question as well, as mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Oh. I removed the '<br />' tag I had written before the '<p>' tag in the html and it worked. Why didn't it work when I added the '<br />' tag?

Comment: Because `p:nth-child` will act like a filter with the `p` in front of it. `nth-child` counts children, regardless of what element it is, and adding the `p` in front of it makes the selector act like a filter.

Comment: are you wanting [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Your answer below shouldn't have been posted as an answer.

Comment: A) Why would you remove the executable snippet I edited into your question? B) If it works when you remove the `<br>` element, what does that tell you? Have you read all the comments and answer? Have you read about how nth-child works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Oh. Thank you. Let me look into that.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the `div` tag is causing the issue. The `:nth-child()` selector selects the nth child of its parent element, regardless of its type. In your case, if the `div` tags are the first child elements of their parent, then they will be selected instead of the `p` tags.

To fix this issue, you can try using the `:first-of-type` selector instead of `:nth-child(1)`. This selector selects the first child element of its type** within its parent element. Here's an example:

```css
div p:first-of-type {
  color: white;
}
```

This will select the first `p` element that is a child of a `div` element and set its color to white.

Comment: Please don't provide guess answers. We can't possibly answer OP's question without seeing their HTML.

Comment: I've added the HTML code. Sorry for the late reply .

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing with your CSS is due to the way the `:nth-child` pseudo-class selector works. The `p:nth-child(1)` selector targets a `<p>` element that is the first child of its parent element. However, in your HTML structure, the first `<p>` element is not the first child of its parent; it's actually preceded by a `<br />` tag.

Here's how it works in your case: `body` is the parent element of the first `<p>`. Inside `body`, the first child is actually the `<br />` tag. Therefore, the `<p>` tag is not the first child, but the second child of body. When you remove the `<br />` tag, the `<p>` tag becomes the first child of its parent, which is why your CSS then correctly applies the white color to it.

To fix this, you can use a different selector that targets the `<p>` tag more accurately. For instance, you can use the `:first-of-type` selector, which selects the first `<p>` element of its kind, regardless of its position among its siblings. Your CSS would then look like this:

```
p:first-of-type {
  color: white;
}
```

This selector will apply the white color to the first `<p>` element within any parent element, regardless of whether other element types come before it.